# AngularJS custom directive ng-repeat, Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-google-maps

In my custom [AngularJS google maps directive](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps), I have map directive and marker directive, marker directive requires map directive.

The following is the simplified version of my problem, which I cannot use ng-repeat.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testapp">
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js"></script>
<script>
var testapp = angular.module('testapp', []);
testapp.directive('map', [
  function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function($scope) {
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html("this will be a map");
      }
    };
  }
]);
testapp.directive('marker', [
  function () {
    return {
      require: '^map',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, mapController) {
        console.log('position', attrs.position);
      }
    };
  }
]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.positions = [[39, -90],[38, -91]];
}
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <map zoom="12" center="[39, -90]">
    <marker ng-repeat='p in positions' position="{{ p }}"></marker>
  </map>
</body>
</html>
```

This is demoed here, http://plnkr.co/edit/IN237QwEdNkdzpDaX70z?p=preview
And the error is,

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:2760:14
    at forEach (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:303:18)
    at forEach.after (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:2759:5)
    at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as after] (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:2825:17)
    at Object.enter (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:3906:17)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:19048:26
    at publicLinkFn (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:5483:29)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:5595:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:6189:18)
    at ngRepeatAction (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js:19046:15)
```

This works well marker directive alone.
http://plnkr.co/edit/4i8Rtvk3Qu1U8JRLRAal?p=preview

I think the problem appears when the parent directive has DOM manipulated.
However, since we are using directive, it must manipulate dom.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are replacing the content of map (marker) with

```
element.html("this will be a map");
```

If instead you try to append it will work without problem.

```
element.append("this will be a map");
```

[Here is a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iwewub/119/edit)

Comment: Thanks, it's that simple.